# Pagination with OrderBy and Jointure

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've a pagination problem that is very annoying, here is my repository code:

```
public function listeSujetsAdmin($forum, $user, $page){
    $builder = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
    $builder
            ->andWhere($builder->expr()->eq('s.forum', ':forum'))
            ->setParameter("forum", $forum->getId())
            ->addSelect('c')
            ->leftJoin('s.commentaires', 'c')
            ->orderBy('c.dateCreation', 'DESC')
            ->addSelect('l')
            ->leftJoin('s.lectures', 'l', Expr\Join::WITH, $builder->expr()->eq('l.user', ':user'))
            ->setParameter('user', $user->getId())
            ->setFirstResult( Sujet::MAX_PAR_PAGE * ($page-1) )
            ->setMaxResults( Sujet::MAX_PAR_PAGE );
    return new Paginator($builder);
}
```

If I keep the "->orderBy('c.dateCreation', 'DESC')", doctrine considers that every commentaires (c) has to be counted where I just want it to count the subjects (s).

This is actually what the profiler shows here:

[image: Profiler]

Thanks everybody !

Comment: So just replace alias `c` with `s`?

Comment: Try to use  it `$query = $this->createQuery("DQL LIKE SQL BUT DQL"); return new Paginator($query->setParameter('user', $user->getId())
            ->setFirstResult( Sujet::MAX_PAR_PAGE * ($page-1) )
            ->setMaxResults( Sujet::MAX_PAR_PAGE ));` I never used query builder, cuz i'm having THE DQL. Yes, paginator can takes Queries without builder (if you use Paginator of Doctrine()).

Comment: I believe its addselect which cause the problem, why not just the join?

Comment: Could you explain in words what you are trying to select? I think it will help. Thanks!

Comment: In words, what I'm trying to do is:
I have three tables in order to make my forum working, one for the subject, one for every message and a last one.
Here I just want to paginate my subjects but I want to order the selection by a row of the second table.
The problem is that Doctrine counts the lines of the second table because I want to order by it, when I still want only to count the lines of the first table.

I'm going to test maches' idea, I'll tell you if that solves my problem !
Thanks for your help !